# Start object from setInterval?

Tags: javascript, sockjs

I have the following reconnect method for Sockjs which almost is fully working:

```
(function() {
  // Initialize the socket & handlers
  var connectToServer = function() {
    var warbleSocket = new SockJS('http://url.com:5555/warble');

    warbleSocket.onopen = function() {
      clearInterval(connectRetry);
      $('.connect-status')
        .removeClass('disconnected')
        .addClass('connected')
        .text('Connected');
    };

    warbleSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
      $('#warble-msg').text(e.data);
    };

    warbleSocket.onclose = function() {
      clearInterval(connectRetry);
      connectRetry = setInterval(connectToServer, 1000);
      $('.connect-status')
        .removeClass('connected')
        .addClass('disconnected')
        .text('Disconnected');
    };

    // Connect the text field to the socket
    $('.msg-sender').off('input').on('input', function() {
      warbleSocket.send($('.msg-sender input').val()); 
    });

    function send(a) {
        warbleSocket.send(a);    
    }

    return {
        send: send
    };
  }();
  var connectRetry = setInterval(connectToServer, 1000);
})();
```

The error i am getting is when its trying to reconnect.
Error is:

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
```

at this line:

```
connectRetry = setInterval(connectToServer, 1000);
```

Any ideas what im doing wrong here?

Comment: The error is caused by something outside this code. You have neither an element list here, nor an opening `[`.

Comment: why do you have `}();` before `var connectRetry = setInterval(connectToServer, 1000);`. Not sure if that is causing issue. It should have been just `};`

Comment: @Rajesh without the `}();` i wont be able to use `connectToServer.send("Hello")` outside of the `connectToServer`

Comment: Actually if i remove the `()` and do `};` it works, but then `connectToServer.send("Hello")` stops to work.

Comment: The point of `connectRetry = setInterval(connectToServer, 1000);` inside the `onclose` is to re-run connectToServer so it tried to reconnect

Answer (score 1):

Your `connectToServer` variable is not a function, it's an object with a property `send` that is a function, so it doesn't make sense to say `setInterval(connectToServer, 1000)`. Try this instead:

```
setInterval(connectToServer.send, 1000);
```

Comment: Se my commend above this would break the logic of my script

Comment: OK, but do you understand the basic point I'm making? `connectToServer` is not a function, so you can't pass it to `setInterval()`. You'll need to restructure your script a bit.

Comment: Yea i understand but just not sure how :/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simplify things a bit?

I would put connection stuff inside a specific function and call it from setInterval().

Something like this (use with care since I'm not testing this code, ok?):

```
(function() {
  // Initialize the socket & handlers
  var connectToServer = function() {
    var warbleSocket;

    function connect() { 
      warbleSocket = new SockJS('http://url.com:5555/warble');

      warbleSocket.onopen = function() {
        // ...
      };

      warbleSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        // ... 
      };

      warbleSocket.onclose = function() {
        // ...
    }

    // Connect the text field to the socket
    $('.msg-sender').off('input').on('input', function() {
      warbleSocket.send($('.msg-sender input').val()); 
    });

    function send(a) {
        warbleSocket.send(a);    
    }

    return {
        send: send
    };
  }();

  // you probably will need to call the first connection
  connectToServer();

  // and than set connection retry
  var connectRetry = setInterval(connectToServer.connect, 1000);
})();
```

I hope it helps you.

Regards,

Heleno